# Cannot install bcrypt-ruby on vagrant machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

I have followed the instructions for setting up a vagrant rails dev box from https://github.com/rails/rails-dev-box. Unfortunately when I attempt to bundle I get the following:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean
sh: 1: make: not found

make "DESTDIR="
sh: 1: make: not found

make failed, exit code 127

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86-linux/2.0.0/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I try and run that gem install command I get the same issue. I have done some searching and am at a loss. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `bcrypt-ruby` gem is trying to compile native (c, c++) code.
It looks like your VM is missing some tools required to compile this native code.

Get a shell to the VM:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Then installing these packages *should* solve the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install make g++ gcc libssl-dev
```

Run bundle install after that.

Comment: Boom! That worked great. Thank you so much for your input. If you have time could you please elaborate on what lead you to that conclusion? I'd like to take away as much from this roadblock as I can and learn about Unix systems more.

Comment: This message `sh: 1: make: not found` explains everything : if the 'make' command is not found, then the corresponding software package is not installed. And I made an educated guess that if you didn't have make, you wouldn't have the compilers (gcc, g++) either.